# BigQuery code failing due to MemoryError using pandas python client library

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am hitting google bigquery using python client library and converting into pandas dataframe and then ultimately converting into csv file. but the code is failing with Memory Error.
The no of counts as of now in table is 74567 after unnesting it is something 1.8mn.

I am currently using python client library to perform these steps.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account



credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(json_key)

def query_to_dataframe(sql_statement):

        return pd.read_gbq(sql_statement,
                     project_id=project_id,
                     credentials=credentials,
                     dialect='standard')


sql_statement = """SELECT visitorId,
visitNumber,
visitId,
visitStartTime,
date,
totals.visits,
totals.hits,
totals.pageviews,
totals.timeOnSite,
totals.bounces,
totals.transactions,
totals.transactionRevenue,
totals.newVisits,
totals.screenviews,
totals.uniqueScreenviews,
totals.timeOnScreen,
totals.totalTransactionRevenue,
totals.sessionQualityDim,
trafficSource.referralPath,
trafficSource.campaign,
trafficSource.source,
trafficSource.medium,
trafficSource.keyword,
trafficSource.adContent,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.campaignId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adGroupId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.creativeId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.page,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.slot,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaParameters,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.gclId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.customerId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adNetworkType,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.targetingCriteria.boomUserlistId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.isVideoAd,
trafficSource.isTrueDirect,
trafficSource.campaignCode,
device.browser,
device.browserVersion,
device.browserSize,
device.operatingSystem,
device.operatingSystemVersion,
device.isMobile,
device.mobileDeviceBranding,
device.mobileDeviceModel,
device.mobileInputSelector,
device.mobileDeviceInfo,
device.mobileDeviceMarketingName,
device.flashVersion,
device.javaEnabled,
device.language,
device.screenColors,
device.screenResolution,
device.deviceCategory,
geoNetwork.continent,
geoNetwork.subContinent,
geoNetwork.country,
geoNetwork.region,
geoNetwork.metro,
geoNetwork.city,
geoNetwork.cityId,
geoNetwork.networkDomain,
geoNetwork.latitude,
geoNetwork.longitude,
geoNetwork.networkLocation,
cd.index,
cd.value,
h.hitNumber,
h.time,
h.hour,
h.minute,
h.isSecure,
h.isInteraction,
h.isEntrance,
h.isExit,
h.referer,
h.page.pagePath,
h.page.hostname,
h.page.pageTitle,
h.page.searchKeyword,
h.page.searchCategory,
h.page.pagePathLevel1,
h.page.pagePathLevel2,
h.page.pagePathLevel3,
h.page.pagePathLevel4,
h.transaction.transactionId,
h.transaction.transactionRevenue as tRevenue,
h.transaction.transactionTax,
h.transaction.transactionShipping,
h.transaction.affiliation,
h.transaction.currencyCode,
h.transaction.localTransactionRevenue,
h.transaction.localTransactionTax,
h.transaction.localTransactionShipping,
h.transaction.transactionCoupon,
h.item.transactionId as tId,
h.item.productName,
h.item.productCategory,
h.item.productSku,
h.item.itemQuantity,
h.item.itemRevenue,
h.item.currencyCode as cCode,
h.item.localItemRevenue,
h.contentInfo.contentDescription,
h.appInfo.name,
h.appInfo.version,
h.appInfo.id,
h.appInfo.installerId,
h.appInfo.appInstallerId,
h.appInfo.appName,
h.appInfo.appVersion,
h.appInfo.appId,
h.appInfo.screenName,
h.appInfo.landingScreenName,
h.appInfo.exitScreenName,
h.appInfo.screenDepth,
h.exceptionInfo.description,
h.exceptionInfo.isFatal,
h.exceptionInfo.exceptions,
h.exceptionInfo.fatalExceptions,
h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
h.eventInfo.eventAction,
h.eventInfo.eventLabel,
h.eventInfo.eventValue,
hp.productSKU as pSKU,
hp.v2ProductName,
hp.v2ProductCategory,
hp.productVariant,
hp.productBrand,
hp.productRevenue,
hp.localProductRevenue,
hp.productPrice,
hp.localProductPrice,
hp.productQuantity,
hp.productRefundAmount,
hp.localProductRefundAmount,
hp.isImpression,
hp.isClick,
hpc.index as hpcIndex,
hpc.value as hpcValue,
hpCustomMetrics.index as cusomMetricsIndex,
hpCustomMetrics.value as cusomMetricsValue,
hp.productListName,
hp.productListPosition,
hp.productCouponCode,
hpromotion.promoId, 
hpromotion.promoName,
hpromotion.promoCreative,
hpromotion.promoPosition,
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsView,
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick,
h.refund.refundAmount,
h.refund.localRefundAmount,
h.eCommerceAction.action_type,
h.eCommerceAction.step,
h.eCommerceAction.option,
hExperiment.experimentId,
hExperiment.experimentVariant,
h.publisher.dfpClicks,
h.publisher.dfpImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpQueries,
h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.dfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adxClicks,
h.publisher.adxImpressions,
h.publisher.adxMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adxMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxQueries,
h.publisher.adxRevenue,
h.publisher.adxViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsViewed,
h.publisher.adsUnitsViewed,
h.publisher.adsUnitsMatched,
h.publisher.viewableAdsViewed,
h.publisher.measurableAdsViewed,
h.publisher.adsPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsClicked,
h.publisher.adsRevenue,
h.publisher.dfpAdGroup,
h.publisher.dfpAdUnits,
h.publisher.dfpNetworkId,
hcustomVariables.index as hcustomVariableIndex,
hcustomVariables.customVarName,
hcustomVariables.customVarValue,
hcustomDimensions.index as customDimensionsIndex,
hcustomDimensions.value as customDimensionsvalue,
hcustomMetrics.index as hcustoMetricsIndex,
hcustomMetrics.value as hcustomMetricsValue,
h.type,
h.social.socialInteractionNetwork,
h.social.socialInteractionAction,
h.social.socialInteractions,
h.social.socialInteractionTarget,
h.social.socialNetwork,
h.social.uniqueSocialInteractions,
h.social.hasSocialSourceReferral,
h.social.socialInteractionNetworkAction,
h.latencyTracking.pageLoadSample,
h.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime,
h.latencyTracking.pageDownloadTime,
h.latencyTracking.redirectionTime,
h.latencyTracking.speedMetricsSample,
h.latencyTracking.domainLookupTime,
h.latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime,
h.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime,
h.latencyTracking.domLatencyMetricsSample,
h.latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime,
h.latencyTracking.domContentLoadedTime,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingValue,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingSample,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingVariable,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingCategory,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingLabel,
sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName,   
sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup1,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup2,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup3,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup4,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup5,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup1,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup2,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup3,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup4,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup5,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews1,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews3,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews4,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews5,
h.dataSource,
hpublisher.dfpClicks as hpublisherDfpclicks,
hpublisher.dfpImpressions as hpublisherDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpQueries as hpublisherDfpQueries,
hpublisher.dfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.dfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.dfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpPagesViewed as hpublisherDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpClicks,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpQueries,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adxClicks as hpublisherAdxClicks,
hpublisher.adxImpressions as hpublisherAdxImpressions,
hpublisher.adxMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdxMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adxMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdxMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxQueries as hpublisherAdxQueries,
hpublisher.adxRevenue as hpublisherAdxRevenue,
hpublisher.adxViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdxViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxPagesViewed as hpublisherAdxPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsViewed as hpublisherAdsViewed,
hpublisher.adsUnitsViewed as hpublisherAdsUnitsViewed,
hpublisher.adsUnitsMatched as hpublisherAdsUnitsMatched,
hpublisher.viewableAdsViewed as hpublisherViewableAdsViewed,
hpublisher.measurableAdsViewed as hpublisherMeasurableAdsViewed,
hpublisher.adsPagesViewed as hpublisherAdsPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsClicked as hpublisherAdsClicked,
hpublisher.adsRevenue as hpublisherAdsRevenue,
hpublisher.dfpAdGroup as hpublisherDfpAdGroup,
hpublisher.dfpAdUnits as hpublisherDfpAdUnits,
hpublisher.dfpNetworkId as hpublisherDfpNetworkId,
fullVisitorId,
userId,
clientId,
channelGrouping,
socialEngagementType


FROM `project_id.dataset.table`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(customDimensions) as cd
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) as h
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.product) as hp
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) as hpc
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hp.customMetrics) as hpCustomMetrics
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.promotion) as hpromotion
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.experiment) as hExperiment
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customVariables) as hcustomVariables
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcustomDimensions
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customMetrics) as hcustomMetrics
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.publisher_infos) as hpublisher"""

df = query_to_dataframe(sql_statement)
df.to_csv("sample1.csv")
```

ERROR:

ConnectionError

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-a51dc6a6e704> in <module>()
    340 LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.publisher_infos) as hpublisher"""
    341 
--> 342 df = query_to_dataframe(sql_statement)
    343 df.to_csv("sample1.csv")
    344 

<ipython-input-60-a51dc6a6e704> in query_to_dataframe(sql_statement)
     16                      project_id=project_id,
     17                      credentials=credentials,
---> 18                      dialect='standard')
     19 
     20 

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.pyc in read_gbq(query, project_id, index_col, col_order, reauth, auth_local_webserver, dialect, location, configuration, credentials, private_key, verbose)
    147         auth_local_webserver=auth_local_webserver, dialect=dialect,
    148         location=location, configuration=configuration,
--> 149         credentials=credentials, verbose=verbose, private_key=private_key)
    150 
    151 

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.pyc in read_gbq(query, project_id, index_col, col_order, reauth, auth_local_webserver, dialect, location, configuration, credentials, verbose, private_key)
    834         private_key=private_key,
    835     )
--> 836     schema, rows = connector.run_query(query, configuration=configuration)
    837     final_df = _parse_data(schema, rows)
    838 

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.pyc in run_query(self, query, **kwargs)
    484         except self.http_error as ex:
    485             self.process_http_error(ex)
--> 486         result_rows = list(rows_iter)
    487         total_rows = rows_iter.total_rows
    488         schema = {

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\page_iterator.pyc in _items_iter(self)
    202     def _items_iter(self):
    203         """Iterator for each item returned."""
--> 204         for page in self._page_iter(increment=False):
    205             for item in page:
    206                 self.num_results += 1

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\page_iterator.pyc in _page_iter(self, increment)
    239                 self.num_results += page.num_items
    240             yield page
--> 241             page = self._next_page()
    242 
    243     @abc.abstractmethod

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\page_iterator.pyc in _next_page(self)
    359         """
    360         if self._has_next_page():
--> 361             response = self._get_next_page_response()
    362             items = response.get(self._items_key, ())
    363             page = Page(self, items, self.item_to_value)

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\table.pyc in _get_next_page_response(self)
   1304             params["maxResults"] = self._page_size
   1305         return self.api_request(
-> 1306             method=self._HTTP_METHOD, path=self.path, query_params=params
   1307         )
   1308 

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.pyc in _call_api(self, retry, **kwargs)
    379         if retry:
    380             call = retry(call)
--> 381         return call()
    382 
    383     def get_dataset(self, dataset_ref, retry=DEFAULT_RETRY):

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.pyc in retry_wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    268                 sleep_generator,
    269                 self._deadline,
--> 270                 on_error=on_error,
    271             )
    272 

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.pyc in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, deadline, on_error)
    177     for sleep in sleep_generator:
    178         try:
--> 179             return target()
    180 
    181         # pylint: disable=broad-except

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\_http.pyc in api_request(self, method, path, query_params, data, content_type, headers, api_base_url, api_version, expect_json, _target_object)
    313             content_type=content_type,
    314             headers=headers,
--> 315             target_object=_target_object,
    316         )
    317 

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\_http.pyc in _make_request(self, method, url, data, content_type, headers, target_object)
    190         headers["User-Agent"] = self.USER_AGENT
    191 
--> 192         return self._do_request(method, url, headers, data, target_object)
    193 
    194     def _do_request(

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\_http.pyc in _do_request(self, method, url, headers, data, target_object)
    219         :returns: The HTTP response.
    220         """
--> 221         return self.http.request(url=url, method=method, headers=headers, data=data)
    222 
    223     def api_request(

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport\requests.pyc in request(self, method, url, data, headers, **kwargs)
    206 
    207         response = super(AuthorizedSession, self).request(
--> 208             method, url, data=data, headers=request_headers, **kwargs)
    209 
    210         # If the response indicated that the credentials needed to be

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\Users\asmohammad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    496 
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 
    500         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error("(10060, 'WSAETIMEDOUT')",))
```

Comment: In general, if you doubt result set is too big to fit in memory, set limit in your query to prove it. If true, try to use cursor based interface fetch one row at a time and process then fetch next.

Comment: @Zhang I tried with smaller table data It was having around 8 lakh of records and it converted successfully but when I increased the size It is failing. so, I am not aware of cursor kind of thing. could you please help me to understand about that?

Comment: This [github post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5859)  should resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pd.read_gbq() is trying to load everything into memory and causing the MemoryError.

You may try iterating over the results the same query using just google-cloud-bigquery facilities? E.g.:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client

client = Client()
query = client.query(sql)
row_count = 0 
for row in query:
    row_count += 1
```

You could also try converting to a dataframe directly using google-cloud-bigquery:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client

client = Client()
query = client.query(sql)
dataframe = query.to_dataframe()
```

Comment: Thank you Zhang for your inputs, I will try the above approach and will keep you posted about the progress.

Comment: @Zhang, I tried above approach as well but no luck, that too is also failing with Memory error.

Comment: @sam, if what you tried was query.to_dataframe(), the [post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5859) has a patch which I don't know whether or not officially released to bq API. However, the first one should work right?

Comment: @Zhang I am able to run the first program that is not my requirement it will give only the no of rows

Comment: @sam, it means you just need a way of converting row into a dataframe. Try to check source code of to_dataframe to see how the library does it.

Comment: Thank you zhang for your support . I will look into it.